# How can I change the default font size of a XRRichText?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress, richtext

I can´t find the way to change the size for my XRRichText, I change in properties the font size, but when I execute my project, do not save the changes that I made.

can anyone suggest me how to change the font size for a XRRichText? thanks.

Comment: I don't have devexpress (neither experience in this specific control). Although something which usually works with the .NET controls is redefining the given font at runtime. For example: `control.Font = New Font("Arial", 10)`.

Comment: Can you share code from which you are setting font size in the control..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the suggestions here - [How do I change Default Font for XRRichText.](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q254640.aspx)

> This is expected behavior of a bound XRRichText control. Please review
>   the [XRRichTextEdit font](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q254640.aspx) thread where this question has been
>   answered.

Please use an instance of the RichEditControl to change the font in the XRRichText control on ***XtraReport.BeforePrint*** event. There you can set the rtf in the control to display it with custom font. Here is some sample code:

```
   ...
        public XtraReport1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.xrRichText1.Html = @"<html><head><title>MyTitle</title></head><body><p>Test</p></body></html>";
        }

        private void XtraReport1_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
        {
            RichEditControl richEditControl1 = new RichEditControl();
            richEditControl1.RtfText = this.xrRichText1.Rtf;
            Document doc = richEditControl1.Document;
            DocumentRange range = richEditControl1.Document.Range;
            CharacterProperties cp = doc.BeginUpdateCharacters(range);
            cp.FontName = "Comic Sans MS";
            cp.FontSize = 18;
            cp.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
            cp.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            cp.Underline = UnderlineType.DoubleWave;
            cp.UnderlineColor = Color.White;
            doc.EndUpdateCharacters(cp);
            this.xrRichText1.Rtf = richEditControl1.RtfText;
            richEditControl1.Dispose();
        }
    ...
```

[XrRichText Default Font](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q274423)
Another approach is that  you can also use the FormatString setting for the HTML binding. Setting the formatstring to this will do the trick.

```
FormatString = <div style="font-family:Arial; font-size:9.75pt;">{0}</div>
```

It worked, even if my HTML value contains  `<head>` and `<body>` elements.

**References:**
[Web Report Designer - How to specify default font](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T286534)
[XRRichText - Font settings aren't applied correctly](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B38722)

Hope this help..

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you - setting the xrRichText field DataBinding > Html  > FormatString worked perfectly.